# bitmap image file size

Tags: image, textures, multimedia

Bitmap images contain pure representation of raw data. A 512x512 24bit bitmap image (like game textures) is 768KB in size, as it should be. Why a 512x512, but 8-bit instead of 256KB, is 257KB? Also a 256x256 8-bit image is 65KB instead of 64! (66,614 bytes instead of 65536 bytes); but for the 24 bit one, it is exactly as it should be.
Thanks...I'm confused.

Comment: Bitmaps also contain headers. Depends on the bitmap formats. There are bitmaps in which run length encoding is also done.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "bitmap image"? It is true that they contain raw data, but they may contain a header also.
And/Or there could be some rounding error in whatever interface is telling you "65 Kb". What is the exact length in bytes for the 64K image? Is it 65536 bytes, or something more?

Comment: hi, Bitmap image I mean Bitmaps! An image format, as you can see in photo editors...that's why I'm wondering; it is 66,614 bytes. but for the 24 bit one, it is exactly as it should be.